# Remove a Div when Input not focused JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my first call for help, so first of all Thanks. 
My problem at the moment is that I'm struggle on way to hide a DIV when a specific Input is not focused and also the Div it self is not  clicked.

For better Understanding, its a live search in a JSON Object, where I get suggestions on the value that has been typed in. 
[Search with Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9eHP.png)

HTML Code Snippet:

```
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-2" id="isFocus">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input placeholder="Analyseverzeichnis" class="form-control input-lg analyseIndex align-middle" id="searchData">
                <span class="input-group-addon icon-search" id="buttonSearch"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="resultWrapper">
                <ul class="list-group" id="resultData"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS Code Snippet:

```
$('#resultData').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
    var getData = $('#searchData').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
    $("#resultData").html('');
    var uri = encodeURIComponent($('#searchData').val());
     window.open('*****Link to JSON File******search='+uri, '_blank');
});
```

The Clou is to hide "the suggestions/list element" only the input field get out of focus and "the suggestions/list element" has not clicked it-self.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input placeholder="Analyseverzeichnis" class="form-control input-lg analyseIndex align-middle" onfocus="document.querySelector('.resultWrapper').style.display='block'" onblur="setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('.resultWrapper').style.display='none'},100)" id="searchData">

    <script>
    document.querySelector('.resultWrapper').style.display='none';
    </script>
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I wanted the wrapper to show up when there are suggestions. And it should only be hidden in the following scenarios: An element (<li>) is selected, or the input field loses the focus.

However, the input field already loses focus when you select an element. And that's my problem. I want you to be able to select one element and then be redirected to another page as in my case.

Comment: What  you did is this: 
When Site Loads (Hide Wrapper)
 then if Input is Focus (Show Wrapper)

When leave Input Field, (Fade Wrapper Away). 

But keep in mind that the Wrapper is important if you want to click something suggestion. If you click, the first thing what happens is, the input get blur. Then you fadeOut the Wrapper. So there is nothing more to click.

And thats the main problem :) 
Anyway, thanks for your help buddy.